# Splitting "either...or" struct over several sentences

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I want to distinguish two options by using the "either...or" structure.
However, as I have to explain the first option, the "or" part would start in a new sentence. Is this good style? Personally, I wouldn't like to start a sentence with "or". Which other options do I have?

Example:

> One has two options: Either you do the first option. This requires several considerations. **Or** you do the second option.

Comment: "Either you so the first option, which requires several considerations, or you do the second (option)"

Comment: Well for the given example this would work, but if the additional information between the options (in my example the required considerations) is much bigger, it would stretch the sentence a lot.

Comment: @BillJ You should write an answer with some explanation why your example works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the words *either … or*.

> One option is to place the birdhouse on a pole beside the mailbox.  This requires obtaining a suitable pole, digging a hole and so on.  It has the disadvantage of possibly annoying the mail carrier.  Alternatively, we can skip the birdhouse idea and go get a pizza.